# Left join returns blanks

Tags: join, sas, left-join, sas-studio

I have performed a left join where the left table has 500,000 observations. In some cases the left join has been successful for Business_Line = "Retail" where as the next observation is left blank, why is this?

the code I used:

```
proc sql;
create table joined2 as
select a.*
      ,b.Join1
      ,b.Join2
      ,b.Join3
from joined as a
left join Sasdata.Assumptions as b
on a.Business_Line = b.Business_Line;
quit;
```

the two tables look like

```
data joined;
input Business_Line $;
datalines;
Retail
Retail
Retail
Business
Business
;
run;
```

the table to join looks like

```
data sasdata.assumptions;
input Business_Line $ Join1 Join2 Join3;
datalines;
Retail 10% 10% 10%
Business 20% 10% 5%
;
run;
```

the current resulting table looks like

```
 business_line join1 join2 join3
 Retail 10% 10% 10%
 Retail . . .
 Business 20% 10% 5%
 Business . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code does not demonstrate the issue.

Indeed, missing values for `join1-join3` will not happen when the actual business_lines values are `'Retail'` or `Business`.  You get a result with 3x1 rows with Retail and 2x1 rows with Business.

The missing values occur when the join key in the left table does not have a corresponding match in the right table.  This can *appear* to happen in SAS if the variables are formatted.

Suppose business_line was an integer with formatted value

```
proc format;
  value line
    101 = 'Retail'
    102 = 'Retail'
    103 = 'Retail'
    201 = 'Business'
    202 = 'Business'
  ;
```

Updated data with formatted business_line

```
data joined;
input Business_Line;
format Business_Line line.;
datalines;
101
102
102
201
202
run;    

data assumptions;
input Business_Line Join1 Join2 Join3;
format Business_Line line.;
datalines;
101 10 10 10
201 20 10  5
run;
```

Join that has some unmatched underlying values

```
proc sql;
create table joined2 as
select a.*
      ,b.Join1
      ,b.Join2
      ,b.Join3
from joined as a
left join Assumptions as b
on a.Business_Line = b.Business_Line;
quit;

options nocenter; ods listing;
proc print data=joined2;
run;
```

Has results demonstrating missing values

```
       Business_
Obs      Line       Join1    Join2    Join3

 1     Retail         10       10       10
 2     Retail          .        .        .
 3     Retail          .        .        .
 4     Business       20       10        5
 5     Business        .        .        .
```

Comment: Does this occur even though 75% of the observations do join but then suddenly cuts off for the same business name label?

Comment: If the variables are not formatted, and you are still getting seemingly non-matches, you may have data value issues, such as leading or trailing non-space whitespace characters.  I would recommend doing a Proc FREQ of the join variables in each data set.  If you have two rows that look the same (business_line) you have a data issue.